# Showing the user details in the header of an Angular application

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show my users avatar in the site header of an Angular 2+ . application.  I get the avatar from a JWT token that I decode in a user service, however it is always undefined in my component.

This is my HeaderComponent:

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  currentAvatar: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentAvatar = this.userService.getHeader();
    // At this point, currentAvatar is always undefined
  }
```

My user service:

```
@Injectable()

export class UserService {

    private avatar: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + '/auth/login', { username: username, password: password }, { headers })
            .map(res => {
                let jwtData = res.auth_token.split('.')[1]
                let decodedJwtJsonData = window.atob(jwtData)
                let decodedJwtData = JSON.parse(decodedJwtJsonData)

                this.avatar = decodedJwtData.avatar;
            });
    }

    getHeader(): UserHeader {
        console.log(this.avatar);
        return this.avatar;

    }

}
```

Comment: where is the `name` declared in `UserService`?

Comment: Sorry that was a type, I've changed it to this.avatar

Comment: you are not subscribing to the method `login` when is the service call is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your operation is asynchronous (you are trying to show the avatar, which you don't have yet cause it comes from the HTTP POST result), at the point you read it, it is still undefined.

You should be returning an Observable of it:

```
getHeader(): Observable<UserHeader> {
    console.log(this.avatar); // undefined here
    return Observable.of(this.avatar);
}
```

And then subscribe to such observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.getHeader().subscribe(
      response => this.currentAvatar = response
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an `async` operation and trying to get data in a `sync` manner that is the reason it is undefined.

You might be better of getting the data in the component at login by subscribing to the login  method and returning the avatar to the component and set it to the `this.currentAvatar`

Answer (score 1):

Your "header" don't have account about the change on the value of this.avatar in your service. To achieve this, you can use a getter or subscribe to the change as Antonio Ortells's answer

```
//in your header.component, make a getter
get avatar()
{
    return this.userService.getHeader()
}
constructor (private userService:UserService)
//And in the .html
{{avatar}}
```